# A good start to learn multi-thread Java crawler

Tags: java, multithreading, web-crawler

I'm developing a web crawler in Java. I'm looking for a good project to develop this crawler based on it. However there are literally more than a few hundred crawlers written in Java. What I'm looking for, is a **fairly simple** crawler that has:

- Multi-thread functionality
- Good performance
- **Implemented based on latest Java builds and new technologies**
- A good documentation
- Not a lot of un-necessary features (bloats)
- Ability to be easily integrated to my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I'm looking for, is a fairly simple crawler...

You're not really going to find that, there is nothing simple about a crawler! Case and point, there is nothing simple about having these features (especially the last bullet point):

- Multi-thread functionality
- Good performance
- Implemented based on latest Java builds and new technologies
- A good documentation
- Not a lot of un-necessary features (bloats)
- Ability to be easily integrated to my project

Nutch is a full featured Java crawler that fulfills most of your requirements: http://nutch.apache.org/

Additionally, I would recommend you check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495289/what-is-a-good-java-web-crawler-library